# Having issues for responsive site

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am having an issue to detect when I am on a mobile phone, tablet and on a desktop/laptop? I was wondering what I am doing wrong. I have provided the code and it is not complete but I do not understand why when I resize the screen from mobile device to desktop/laptop display, everything is out of place. I am wondering how do I reset so when I go back to desktop view? Also have in issue with resizing the images I have displayed on my sites. I would like to resize accordingly with the size of the device. I have a logo image and a banner image and on top of these two images is the navigation bar which I am also having issue with resizing and making it transparent due to having the navigation bar on top of a grey background. How can I make it transparent on the banner and logo. I appreciate all the help I have gotten so far. I have progress a lot. Thank You guys!

Here is the html code:

```
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="selected" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="chat.html">Get Help</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://community.yesican.org">Community</a></li>
            <li><a href="resources.html">Resources</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About YIC</a></li>
            <li><a href="supportyic.html">Get Involved</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>


<img id="banner" src="img/banner.jpg"/>
<!--The main content of the website will go inside of the #wrapper id. It is divided into two sections: #primary & #secondary.-->
<div id="wrapper">
    <!-- Two sections have been created for desktop view to have two columns. Mobile website will just be stacked-->
    <div id="content">
        <section id="primary"><!--Left column content goes here-->
            <h2>Who We Are</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean in elementum velit, venenatis rhoncus lacus. Ut consequat luctus enim, in auctor libero posuere ut. Curabitur vitae aliquet nisi. Etiam condimentum tincidunt venenatis. Fusce vel congue purus. Pellentesque ut eleifend ex. Nunc purus neque, aliquam vitae aliquam quis, accumsan id lacus. Nunc ac scelerisque magna. Etiam purus lorem, rutrum et ornare a, tincidunt non ipsum. Nullam blandit dui venenatis, malesuada felis a, porttitor purus.</p>
            <p><a href="#">This is how a link looks.</a></p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean in elementum velit, venenatis rhoncus lacus. Ut consequat luctus enim, in auctor libero posuere ut. Curabitur vitae aliquet nisi. Etiam condimentum tincidunt venenatis. Fusce vel congue purus. Pellentesque ut eleifend ex. Nunc purus neque, aliquam vitae aliquam quis, accumsan id lacus. Nunc ac scelerisque magna. Etiam purus lorem, rutrum et ornare a, tincidunt non ipsum. Nullam blandit dui venenatis, malesuada felis a, porttitor purus.</p>
        </section>

        <section id="secondary"><!--Right column content goes here-->
            <h2>Memorial</h2>
            <img src="img/memorial_list.jpg"/>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean in elementum velit, venenatis rhoncus lacus. Ut consequat luctus enim, in auctor libero posuere ut.</p>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>

<!--Footer still needs to be completed-->
<footer>
    <div id="footer-right">
        <ul><h3>ABOUT</h3>
            <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="">FAQ's</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Site Map</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul><h3>SUPPORT OUR CAUSE</h3>
            <li><a href="">Donate</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Volunteer</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Fundraising Events</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul><h3>FOLLOW US</h3>
            <li>
                <a href="#Facebook handle here"><img src="img/facebook-icon.png" alt="Facebook Logo" class="social-icon"></a>
                <a href="#Instagram handle here"><img src="img/instagram-icon.png" alt="Instagram Logo" class="social-icon"></a>
                <a href="#Twitter handle here"><img src="img/twitter-icon.png" alt="Twitter Logo" class="social-icon"/></a>
                <a href="#Pinterest handle here"><img src="img/pinterest-icon.png" alt="Pinterest Logo" class="social-icon"/></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="footer-left">
        <p id="footer-slogan">BREAK THE <strong>SILENCE</strong> <br>AND <strong>CYCLE</strong> OF ABUSE</p>
        <p id="copyright">Copyright&copy; 2014 International Child Advocacy Network</p>
    </div>
</footer>
```

here is the responisve.css code:

```
  /*This is the placeholder for responsive CSS that we will implement for mobile design*/

  /* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
  @media only screen 
  and (min-device-width : 320px) 
  and (max-device-width : 480px) {
  /* Styles */

#content{
text-align:center;
}
#body{
  float left; font-family:Fabrica
 }
#nav{
 text align:center; font-size:.9em;
}
 }

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
@font-face {
font-family: 'Fabrica';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 100;
src: local('Fabrica'), local('Fabrica'), url(path/Fabrica.otf) format('otf');
}

}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
@font-face {
 font-family: 'Fabrica';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 100;
src: local('Fabrica'), local('Fabrica'), url(path/Fabrica.otf) format('otf');
}

}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
 @media only screen 
 and (min-device-width : 768px) 
 and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
 /* Styles */
```

}

```
/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px)  
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}

 /* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
 @media only screen 
 and (min-width : 1224px) {
 /* Styles */
 }

 /* Large screens ----------- */
 @media only screen 
 and (min-width : 1824px) {
 /* Styles */
 }

 /* iPhone 4 ----------- */
 @media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
 only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
 /* Styles */
 }
 /*************************************
TWO COLUMN LAYOUT

 Will target anything larger than average smartphone.
 This is helpful for normal sized tablets, very large smartphones, and very small desktop   windows.
 ***************************************/

 #primary {
width: 50%;
 float: left;
  padding:10px;
 }
 #secondary {
 width: 40%;
 float: right;
 padding:10px;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use  bootstrap for that?

Comment: Not really sure how to use bootstrap. New to all this

Comment: Is there a tutorial you can reference that can help

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: @Banzay Bootstrap does not detect devices, it serves CSS based on widths in the CSS only. Devices come in all shapes and sizes and so you could be on a tablet that is just as wide as a desktop viewport and get those styles.

Comment: I have updated my issue to better explain what is wrong with my code. Any help will help. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#primary, #secondary {
    dialay:inline-block;
    width:45%;
    padding:.5%;
    margin:.5%;
}
```

The same style will work for both divs. No need for floating. Then you should wrap BOTH of them together in a:

```
<dig align=center><div id="primary"><div id="secondary"></div>
```

And they should be good.

Comment: I actually resolved the issue but that looks like it would work as well. Thank you

Comment: I have updated my question to better reflect the issue I am having

Comment: what is the center for?

Comment: That way the two divs don't hang to the left